Gibberish output for PyTesseract OCR
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
def extract_text(image):
    gray = image.convert('L')
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(gray)
    enhanced_image = enhancer.enhance(2)
    enhanced_image = enhanced_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=.3))
    enhanced_image.save("processed_image.png")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(enhanced_image, config='--psm 12')
    print(f'{text=}')
    return text

@interactions.slash_command("predict", description="Predict the location of an uploaded image")
@interactions.slash_option("image", "Upload an image", opt_type=interactions.OptionType.ATTACHMENT, required=True)
async def predict(ctx: interactions.SlashContext, image: interactions.Attachment):
    await ctx.defer()
    url = image.url
    image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw).convert("RGB")
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
    enhanced_image = enhancer.enhance(1.3)

    # Convert the enhanced image to a tensor and ensure values are in the range [0, 1]
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
    image_tensor = transform(enhanced_image).unsqueeze(0).to(device)

    extracted_text = extract_text(enhanced_image)

I am not sure why my pytesseract is returning gibberish, I am unsure why getting these outputs.  That results in the following output:
text = "m ms\n\nnu MvInIA6=Fmcem'x4Ir;u\nq Dnvuvauou 53523\n\n3 mm nyzenq795nx3I)1r>cmePmoe:.x\n- 531463 my\n\n1; I92I)xl2I)0,IMHz\n\n"

I have tried changing the config, changing the filters, removing the filters, etc. I have updated pytesseract via pip, I am not sure what else there is to do. Anything help would be appreciated.

probably you haven't processed the image enough, see doc section Usage

As cards already suggested, some pre-processing would benefit the tesseract results.
For example, you can use OTSU:
imGray = cv2.imread("ComputerInfo.png", 0)
imOTSU = cv2.threshold(imGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

To get the following image:

You will still need to figure out how to remove the symbols. Here's the tesseract output: pytesseract.image_to_string(imOTSU).split("\n")
['MY RIG',
 '',
 'Ww NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090,',
 '$1 Driver version 596.23',
 '',
 'AMD Ryzen 9 7980XaD 16-Core Processor',
 'mm 3.1468 RAM',
 '',
 '1920 1200, 144',
 '']

As you can see the results are flawed in some places, I think this is because the resolution is quite poor. Morphology would not help you here because some letters are one pixel wide. So maybe try resizing and then eroding?
For example, resizing before pytesseract: pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.resize(imOTSU, (600,400))).split("\n")
['MY RIG',
 '',
 'we NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090',
 '',
 '@ Driver version 536.23',
 '',
 '€ AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D 16-Core Processor',
 'MM 63.14 GB RAM',
 '',
 'G) 1920x 1200, 144Hz',
 '']

Hope this helps you further.
